# How to set projects to package in Team City on custom build run

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to set which projects to package on TeamCity build run. To accomplish that I have a custom parameter setup in TeamCity build.
Parameter is set of project names, which is being prompted to be selected from predefined set of values (project names) when running the build.

For the sake of example let's say this custom parameter is:

```
ProjectToPackage: Project1, Project2, Project3
```

Later in the build step nuget pack I want to use this parameter to decide which projects to pack. So, in specification files I had:

```
trunk/*/*.csproj
```

Which is package all projects, which I want now to reflect custom parameter selection, something like this:

```
trunk/*/%ProjectToBuild%.csproj
```

Now this obviously won't work if multiple values are selected, as in cases when multiple values are selected parameter is "," separated string, e.g.if **Project1** and **Project2** selected, *ProjectToPackage* will be *"Project1, Project2"*, as a result specification files selection would turn to:

```
trunk/*/Project1, Project2.csproj
```

Which of course fails.

So I'm looking for a way to be able to input project names to be packaged as a result of TeamCity build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish this had to write some MSBuild script.
Considering there is custom parameter setup which lists all projects to be `packaged` with the name `ProjectsToBuild`, here's the MSBuild `target` that did the job:

```
<Target Name="Pack">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_SelectedProjectItem Include="$(ProjectsToBuild)" />
      <ProjectsToPack Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\*\%(_SelectedProjectItem.Identity).csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(PathToNuGetExe) pack %(ProjectsToPack.FullPath) -OutputDirectory $(OutDir) -IncludeReferencedProjects" />
  </Target>
```